# React: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hey i'm slightly new to react and wondering what i'm doing wrong...

What i'm trying to do:

1. Navbar with a connection button
2. onClick call CreateConnection
3. add Result to localstorage
4. add data to Navbar without refresh

Right now the useEffect doesn't recognize the new addition to localstorage so won't update until page refresh.

Navbar.js:

```
export const Navbar = () => {

    const [connectionAddress, setConnectionAddress] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("address")) {
            setConnectionAddress(localStorage.getItem("address"))
        }
    }, []);


    return (
         <ProfileNav
              address={connectionAddress}
         />

         <input type="submit" value="Connect" onClick={CreateConnection} /> 
    )
}
```

CreateConnection.js

```
const CreateConnection = async () => {

 try {

     #Connection code - when this is finished: 

     window.localStorage.setItem('address', address[0]);

  } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

}
```

ProfileNav.js

```
export const ProfileNav = ({ address }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <li>{address}</li>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProfileNav;
```

If i simply add `window.location.reload(true)` to CreateConnection.js it works but i want it to work without a refresh (possibly with useState

But if i try to put the useState in CreateConnection.js like so:

```
 try {
     const [connectionAddress, setConnectionAddress] = useState("");

     #Connection code - when this is finished: 

     window.localStorage.setItem('address', address[0]);
     setConnectionAddress(address[0])

  } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

}
```

i get the error when i click on the button: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: I think the issue is the `useState` call inside a `try` block - in theory this might not be executed on every render because an error might be thrown before. As it is, this should be fine because it's the first line of the `try` block, and `useState` can't throw an error - so move that line with the `useState` call out of the `try` block and that should (I hope) fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, react hooks are only supposed to be called from React components or from other hooks. There's a few more rules that you should look into as well https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html.

One option moving forward is to return the address from `CreateConnection`, and pass that into `setConnectionAddress` in the `onClick` handler (or a callback) in your component. Another option (less recommended) would be to create a parameter for setState in `CreateConnection` and pass `setConnectionAddress` into `CreateConnection`.

###### CreateConnection.js

We'll add the return, and also name this a bit more appropriately

```js
// would recommend naming this with conventional camelCase
const createConnection = async () => {
  try {
    // Connection code - when this is finished: 
    window.localStorage.setItem('address', address[0]);
    return address[0];
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

###### Navbar.js

Here we a handler `updateConnectionAddress` to update the connection when the button is clicked. We could also put that code in the jsx within `onClick`'s curly braces, but it's usually better to keep the jsx leaner.

```
export const Navbar = () => {
  const [connectionAddress, setConnectionAddress] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("address")) {
      setConnectionAddress(localStorage.getItem("address"))
    }
  }, []);

  const updateConnectionAddress = async () = {
    const newAddress = await createConnection();
    setConnectionAddress(newAddress);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ProfileNav address={connectionAddress} />
      <input type="submit" value="Connect" onClick={updateConnectionAddress} /> 
    </>
  )
}
```

In the spirit of the single responsibility principle, I would likely consider moving the local storage code elsewhere from createConnection as well, but I think that's out of scope for this topic

Comment: Thank you, do you perhaps have an example on how that onclick handler or callback works with my code?

Comment: Thank you so much! i will try this out in a bit - looking at it i think i'll get it working you're awesome